# Secure and private connection to GnuPG keyservers

Tags: gnupg, key-server

I wish to privately submit my public key (without it being sniffed on the internet). I found that I have 3 ways to connect to the keyserver securely:

1. `https://<keyserver-url>`
2. `hkps://<keyserver-url>` (HKP over TLS)
3. `hkp://<keyserver-onion>` [Using TOR]

Which one of the 3 is most secure? I'm surprised to find that the Tor keyservers only use  hkp and not hkps.

https keyservers are working with ipv4 to search and submit keys but it's hard to find hkps server working with ipv4.

Comment: What do you mean _"it's snooping on the internet"_?

Comment: All .onion connections are already end-to-end encrypted, so hpks over tor makes no sense.

Comment: You are afraid of someone getting your _public_ key? What exactly are you trying to protect against?

Comment: "All .onion connections are already end-to-end encrypted, so hpks over tor makes no sense." If all connections are encrypted then why tor-browser uses https-everywhere or it is recommended to use https-everywhere??

Comment: "You are afraid of someone getting your public key? What exactly are you trying to protect against?" Public key never mean that it is linked to some real identity...it can simply mean a real email address and the email service provider can be riseup or any one willing to provide private email. Further fingerprints verification can be requested by a known or trusted party with reliable contact or just be physically present...it's not that the whole world should know whose public key it is on the key-server.

Comment: @ls_milkyway The Tor browser doesn't just access .onion sites, it will work for any website. Plugins like https-everywhere are recommended because if you access a non-.onion site over plain http, traffic from the exit node will be unencrypted and can be analyzed to deanonymize you (in fact, we should assume that all exit nodes are malicious).

Comment: @mricon Hmm...thanks ...that means everything will be safe & protocol (http,https,hkp etc.) is irrelevant on an .onion site ...as connections are already end-to-end encrypted...I guess also using bridges will be more safer (I read it somewhere) with an .onion DNS service.....assuming that there is an OS & firewall with well and safe configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options 1 and 2 seem very similar, since both rely on the TLS protocol, so which is more secure will depend on the nature of the certificates (key size, supported algorithms) and the configuration of the servers (version support).

Tor on the other hand tries to protect the origin of the communication, so it adds an extra layer of protection to hide the address where the request comes from.

There was some paper explaining why TOR may be vulnerable if an observer has [control of several routing AS](https://web.archive.org/web/20130928003811/http://lastor.cs.ucr.edu/oakland12.pdf), but in that case, the observer must have huge control of the network.

If you are the only one using TOR in your context, and your are trying to protect from some sniffer, TOR traffic may at least reveal some of your activity.

Comment: I guess that using bridges in TOR will be more safer (I read it somewhere) with an .onion DNS service.....assuming TOR is running on  safe environment.